# mysqli_num_rows is not working

Tags: php, database, mysqli

What is the main prob with this code? while testing **SELECT count(winner) AS num FROM 
subscribe_user WHERE winner ='yes' AND hitdate=CURDATE()** this code in sql in database sql 
it shows num as 3 
But the code shown below, shows only 1  that should be 3.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bot");
$count_winner=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT count(winner) AS num FROM 
subscribe_user WHERE winner ='yes' AND hitdate=CURDATE()")or 
 die(mysql_error());
$w=mysqli_num_rows($count_winner);
echo $w;
```

Comment: `num as 3` is only 1 result. That's why it's showing `1`

Comment: But i want to print 3 as counted in DB SQL .
How can i do that? @NanaPartykar

Comment: And, when you are counting in query itself the number of winners. Then, why you need `mysqli_num_rows($count_winner);`?

Comment: mysqli_num_rows($count_winner) will print how many people win per day @NanaPartykar

Comment: `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($count_winner); echo $row['num'];`

Comment: If you want the result of the query, `num` comes out as `$count_winner[0]['num']`

Comment: @NanaPartykar add it as an answer.

Comment: `mysql_error()` btw does not mix with the `mysqli_` api. It should be `mysqli_error()` and passing the connection as its (single) argument.

Comment: CONGO MAN
thank u ....@NanaPartykar

Comment: What's `congo man` mean, Congratulations? If the solution works you should accept one of the answers below. @rabibgalib

Comment: Ha Ha `:D` @chris85: I don't know for what purpose I was congratulated. Ha Ha ?

Comment: @NanaPartykar I think congratulations is equal to or better than an accepted answer. I've never received a `congratulations`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bot");
$count_winner = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT count(winner) AS num FROM subscribe_user WHERE winner ='yes' AND hitdate=CURDATE()") or mysqli_error($link));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($count_winner);
echo $row['num']; //Will output the count of number of winners
```

> The [mysqli_num_rows()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp) function returns the number of rows in a result
>   set.

Comment: See the (slight) edit also that I made in the other answer and the comment I left under the question about `mysql_error()` ;-)

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing is expected.  `mysqli_num_rows` gives you the number of rows in your result -- `1`.  The `num` field in your result shows you the value of `count(winner)` -- `3`.  These are different metrics.

> But i want to print 3 as counted in DB SQL . How can i do that?

Instead of grabbing `mysqli_num_rows`, actually read the result:

```
$result = mysqli_query('...') or die('...');    
$w = $result->fetch_assoc()['num'];
```

Also, `mysql_error()` does not mix with the `mysqli_` api. It should be `mysqli_error()` and passing the connection as its (single) argument.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't.